# How to convert a NSData object to a UIImage? Using Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, nsdata

I have an array of images in an NSData array. How do i convert all of them to an image array without doing it manualy? do i use this line of code(`let yourImage = UIImage(data:NsdataArray)`
)

```
var NsdataArray:[AnyObject] = [image1, image2, image3]
//convert everything to this array
var imageArray:[UIImage] = [UIImage]()
```

Comment: Just use a simple for loop.

Comment: How do i make a for loop for this?

Answer (score 4):

```
var imageArray =  NsdataArray.map({UIImage(data: $0)})
```

OR

```
var imageArray = [UIImage]()

    for data in NsdataArray {
        if let img = UIImage(data: data){
           imageArray.append(img)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if there is an error creating an `UIImage` from the data?

Answer (score 3):

Try this `var imageArray = NsdataArray.map({UIImage(data: $0)})`.

Answer (score 2):

for loop solution:

```
var NsdataArray:[AnyObject] = [image1, image2, image3]
//convert everything to this array
var imageArray:[UIImage] = [UIImage]()

for aData in NsdataArray {
   var image = UIImage(data: aData as? NSData) 
   if let _image = image {
       imageArray.append(_image) 
   } else {
       //error when convert to UIImage
   }
}
```